# Can someone explain this function from JsFromHell: Sum of a numeric array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is how JsFromHell defines a function to find sum of a numeric array (http://jsfromhell.com/array/sum)

```
sum = function(o){
    for(var s = 0, i = o.length; i; s += o[--i]);
    return s;
};
//sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Can someone explain what's happening within second part of the for loop? What's the meaning of "i;"? It appears like its same as i >= 0. But that returns a NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript has various ways of coercing non-Boolean values to `true` or `false`.  One of them has to do with numbers: zero is `false`, any other number is `true`.

For strings, an empty string is `false`, others are `true`.  The `null` value is coerced to `false`, as is the somewhat zen-like "undefined" non-value.

You could write that code:

```
for (var s = 0, i = o.length; i > 0; s += o[--i]);
```

and it might be even more efficient. (Or it might not be; it's the kind of micro-optimization that only library maintainers should worry about, since next week the browser vendors may rev their interpreters and flip the situation on its head.)

Finally, if you're getting a `NaN`, it means that you don't really have an array of numbers. If there's a single thing in the array that can't cleanly be converted to a numeric value in the third part of the "for" loop, you'll get a `NaN` result. *edit* — oh wait, I see; you tried `i >= 0` and not `i > 0`. That means the loop will try to access `o[-1]` which is undefined. That'll give you a `NaN` when you try to convert it to a number.

Comment: Hmm, you've changed the prefix decrement to a postfix decrement, which should trigger an out of bounds error (or silently ignored), I'm not sure it's going to improve the perf ;-)

Comment: Right. I was trying i >= 0. Jon's answer explained that part. That would be NaN because of pre-decrement.

Answer (score 3):

Loop as a whole:

```
for(var s = 0, i = o.length; i; s += o[--i]);
```

Loop initialization (this is actually setting up two variables):

```
 var s = 0          // set sum = 0
 var i = o.length   // set "current item index" equal to last index in array
```

Loop test condition (when this becomes false, the loop ends)

```
 i  // so this will become false when i == 0
```

Counting expression:

```
 s += o[--i]
```

This adds the "current" array element's value to the sum, and decrements the loop index to change the "current" array element. **Very importantly**, it uses pre-decrement so that:

- it does not access an out of bounds value (when `i == o.length`, `o[i]` would be out of bounds while the last element would be accessed through `o[i-1]`)
- it actually processes the element at `o[0]` (the way the loop test is written, when `i == 0` the loop would exit immediately so that `o[0]` actually needs to be processed when `i == 1`)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var s = 0, i = o.length; i; s += o[--i]);
```

On the every step following occurs:

1. Check if i is `false`.
2. If it's false stop, continue otherwise. 0 == false. So the loop will stop when `i` will be equal to 0.
3. Subtract 1 from i (`--i`).
4. Add `i` value of `o` to `s`.
5. Go to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Fhe for-loop condition is checking if `i` is truthy ir falsy. Its effect is equivalent to doing `i !== 0`

Answer (score 0):

First it define that `s` is 0 and `i` is the array length

```
var s = 0, i = o.length;
```

Then it pass `i` as it conditional, when JS parse a number format to Boolean, you will see that `0 or less` is `false` and `1 or more` is `true`.

```
i; //is true until it became 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = function(o){
    for(var s = 0, i = o.length; i; s += o[--i]);
    return s;
};
//sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

1st part (declaration):
`s = 0` and `i` = length of array `o`

2nd part(condition)
`i` is going to reflect the array index, which we are starting at the length of array `o`.  If our index becomes `0`, it will be equivalent to `false`.

3rd part(action)
`s` is incremented by the integer in position `--i` of array `o`.  `--` is the deincrement operator, which is equivalent to `i = i-1`.  The position of this operator is important.  Since it's before the letter `i`, the program deincrements `i` before it reads it.  So by the first time it gets there, `i` is already `o.length - 1`.